# Exclude first value on jquery function on mvc dropdown list

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this MVC web application with dropdowns:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Questions1, (SelectList)ViewData["Questions"], "Select>>", new { id = "Questions1", Name = "Questions1"})

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Questions2, (SelectList)ViewData["Questions"], "Select>>", new { id = "Questions2", Name = "Questions2"})
```

And this jquery:

```
// Build a javascript array with all of the select names/values
var options = new Array();
$('#Questions1 option').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    options.push({ Name: $this.text(), Value: $this.val() });
});

// Create a function for re-building a select minus the chosen option
var rebuildSelect = function($selOption, $select) {
    $previouslySelected = $select.find(':selected');
    $select.empty();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        if (opt.Value != $selOption.val()) {
            if ($previouslySelected.val() == opt.Value) {
                $select.append('<option value="' + opt.Value + '" selected="selected">' + opt.Name + '</option>');
            }
            else {
                $select.append('<option value="' + opt.Value + '">' + opt.Name + '</option>');
            }
        }
    }
}

// Wire up the event handlers
var $Questions1 = $('#Questions1');
var $Questions2 = $('#Questions2');

$Questions1.change(function() {
    rebuildSelect($(this), $Questions2);
});

$Questions2.change(function() {
    rebuildSelect($(this), $Questions1);
});

// Go ahead and run the function on each box to remove the default entries from the other box
rebuildSelect($Questions1.find(':selected'), $Questions2);
rebuildSelect($Questions2.find(':selected'), $Questions1);
```

What the jquery code do is to remove the selected value on the first dropdown on the second dropdown so the user won't able to chose two same question.

My problem is the default value of the dropdown which is "Select>>" is being removed from the second dropdown.

Any idea how I can exclude the "Select>>"? Thanks in advance!

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5k99/4/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason you cannot just remove the item you want to remove without rebuilding the control?

Two methods below: One will remove the selected item. The other will remove an item based on its value. Assumes that your values for the options are unique.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <select id="example">
            <option value="1">First</option>
            <option value="2">Second</option>
            <option value="3">Third</option>
        </select></div>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="remove">Remove Selected</a></div>
    <div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="removeSecond">Remove Second</a></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#remove").click(function () {
                var select = $("#example");
                var selected = select.find(":selected");
                selected.remove();
            });

            $("#removeSecond").click(function () {
                var select = $("#example");
                var second = select.find("[value=2]");
                second.remove();
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

Does this do what you want? Instead of empty, I call $select.find("[value!=0]").remove(); and that seems to match the behaviour you're describing.

```
// Build a javascript array with all of the select names/values
var options = new Array();
$('#Questions1 option:not(:first)').each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    options.push({ Name: $this.text(), Value: $this.val() });
});

// Create a function for re-building a select minus the chosen option
var rebuildSelect = function($selOption, $select) {
    $previouslySelected = $select.find(':selected');
    $select.find("[value!=0]").remove();
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        if (opt.Value != $selOption.val()) {
            if ($previouslySelected.val() == opt.Value) {
                $select.append('<option value="' + opt.Value + '" selected="selected">' + opt.Name + '</option>');
            }
            else {
                $select.append('<option value="' + opt.Value + '">' + opt.Name + '</option>');
            }
        }
    }
}

// Wire up the event handlers
var $Questions1 = $('#Questions1');
var $Questions2 = $('#Questions2');

$Questions1.change(function() {
    rebuildSelect($(this), $Questions2);
});

$Questions2.change(function() {
    rebuildSelect($(this), $Questions1);
});

// Go ahead and run the function once to remove the default entry from the second box
rebuildSelect($Questions1.find(':selected'), $Questions2);
```

Comment: The second one matched what I needed to do. Thanks!

Comment: No worries. For future reference with jQuery selectors, try this site: http://api.jquery.com/?s=select+attribute - I had to go there myself to double-check the syntax for the 'attribute not value' selector. That site should be your first port-of-call for jQuery related problems.

Comment: Something is weird. It is working on fiddler but not on my code on visual studio.

Comment: It is working now. I changed ("[value!=0]") to ("[index!=0]"). Thanks again!

Comment: Peculiar. Could be a difference in the jQuery versions or the way the browser is handling jQuery. Anyway, glad you're sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem so what I did was to insert an Alt+255 character in front of the "Select>>" string.  You don't see this Alt+255 char.  It is invisible.  Then on my code I just checked for this first character to exclude it.

Comment: Will you please post some sample codes for your concept? It will be useful for many.